# How to break Line in mutlicell using fpdf in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

```
  $pdf->Multicell(0,8,'Name of Mineral/ore:'.implode(',', $_POST["nom"]),0,1);
  $pdf->SetX(30);
```

using this code I m getting outfit like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsSV9.png)

how can I break this like and see my output in one same line?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a proper width value (2nd argument). Or use [Cell](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) instead... which also requires a width value but doesn't break lines automatically.